# REST API: Resource hierarchy and multiple URI

Tags: rest, restful-url

I work with a banking database, which is structured like this:

```
Table      Primary Key   Unique Keys          Foreign Keys
-------------------------------------------------------------
BANK       ID            BIC           
CUSTOMER   ID            CUSTNO, PASS, CARD   BANK
ACCOUNT    ID            IBAN                 BANK, CUSTOMER
```

I want to design a clean REST API, but I run into following problems:

1. Should I put resources in a hierarchy, or rather flat? The problem with the hierarchy might be that the client only knows the `ACCOUNT ID`, but does not know the `CUSTOMER ID`, so how is he supposed to get the resource?

```
/banks/{id}/customers/{id}/accounts{id}
or
/banks/{id}
/customers/{id}
/accounts{id}
```

2. The primary key in each table is the database `ID`. It is an internal ID and has no business meaning. Is it correct to use it as the default URI of the resource?
3. Each object has its own set of unique keys. For example, `CUSTOMER` can be identified by his `CUSTNO`, `PASS` or `CARD`. Each client only has a subset of these keys. Should I define a sub-resource per key or provide a lookup service that will give the proper URI back?

```
/customers/id/{id}
/customers/custno/{custno}
/customers/pass/{pass}
/customers/card/{card}
or
/lookup/customer?keyType=card&keyValue=AB-303555
 (gives back customer {id})
```

I am asking what is the truly RESTful way, what is best practice. I haven't found proper answers yet.

Comment: what's the main use case? why does a client want to get a customer's details? FWIW, a verb in a url isn't strictly rest, it's more like rpc, e.g. /lookup/ the lookup is implied in /customers/, although I would go for /customer/ as it's a single resource the client wants

Comment: does the client know it has a custno, pass or card? Or can the server work out what is being passed? e.g. by its format? If so, you could just allow the client to get /customer/{the data the client has} and let the server work out whether it's a custno, pass or card

Comment: There are multiple use cases. We have multiple internal systems, which feed the core banking system or retrieve information. For example, a Rating System wants to update client's rating score, CRM wants to add a remark, E-Banking wants to read a list of customer accounts. etc.

Comment: I don't like the /customer as a single resource, since there will definitely be a /customers URL. Maybe then go with GET /customers?keyType&keyValue/id, which would return a list of IDs matching the query parameters? But is this even a valid pattern to use a lookup for finding the "one primary URI" of a resource?

Comment: The client knows the key type, yes. The server may attempt to lookup the object without the key type, but of course a key "1234" may reappear in two different key types, at which point you may get two different objects. It is not nice to lookup keys without specifying the type. Also, is it not ugly to mix different URI types in one? Is it not bad if `/customers/SMITH` and `/customers/1234` point to the same resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am asking what is the truly RESTful way, what is best practice.

REST doesn't care what spellings you use for your identifiers.

```
/ef726381-dd43-4017-9778-83cee2bbbd93
```

is a perfectly RESTful URI, suitable for any use case.

Outside of some purely mechanical concerns, general purpose consumers treat a URI as a single opaque unit.  There's no notion of a consumer extracting semantic information from the URI -- which means that any information encoded into the identifier is done at the server's discretion and for its use alone.

For cases where information known to the client needs to be included in the target-uri of the request, we have [URI Templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570), which are a sort of generalization of a `GET` form in HTML.  So *a* way to think about your problem is to consider what information the client has, and how they would put that information into a form.

HTML's form processing rules are pretty limiting -- general URI templates have fewer constraints.

```
/customers/id/{id}
/customers/custno/{custno}
/customers/pass/{pass}
/customers/card/{card}
```

Having multiple resources sharing common information is normal in REST -- your resource model is not your data model.  So this could be fine.  It's even OK to have multiple resources that share representations.  You could have them stand alone, or you could have them share a `Content-Location`, or a [canonical](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596) link relation, or you could simply have those resources redirect to the canonical resource.

It's all good.

> So you mean if a UUID can be a valid URI, then a table autonumber key can be too?

Yes, exactly.

Note that if you want the lifetime of the URI to extend beyond the lifetime of your current implementation, then you need to design your identifiers with that constraint in mind.  See [Cool URIs Don't Change](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI).

The clients don't care what the URI is, they just want the link to work again when they need it.

Comment: So you mean if a UUID can be a valid URI, then a table autonumber key can be too? And thanks for the point about no semantic meaning of URI for the client, that helps.

Comment: So when I describe a web service in RAML, I should put something like `/customers{?key,type}´ and the the client will call `/customers?key=1234&type=custno`? I need to test if my banking system supports this.

Comment: So do you recommend to use URI template or different resources for different URI to access the same DB record? I guess one issue I might have with statically listing the possible URIs is that it's not as flexible: it bloats the RAML and I have to implement a request handler for each of these endpoints. Whereas with a key/type pair I can implement in a single handler.